# Early Hints or HTTP/2 push with ASP.NET Azure app service

Tags: asp.net, azure, http2, pagespeed

We want to use either HTTP/2 push or Early Hints to get the browser access to stylesheets (and other resources) as soon as possible. This is to improve the time for LCP as reported by Google Search Console's Core Web Vitals.

With **[HTTP/2 push](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.pushpromise)**, our attempts have been thwarted by Azure's partial support for HTTP/2, which results in an UnauthorizedAccessException when calling PushPromise, e.g. `HttpContext.Response.PushPromise("/css/main.css");`. [Microsoft say](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/frontdoor/front-door-http2):

> HTTP/2 protocol support is available only for requests from clients to Front Door. The communication from Front Door to back ends in the back-end pool happens over HTTP/1.1.

Furthermore, support for PushPromise in ASP.NET CORE has been [considered and rejected](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4249#issuecomment-728363386).

With **[Early Hints](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc8297.html)**, our attempts have been thwarted by the lack of support in the Microsoft stack for sending a 103 informational response, as discussed (and parked) at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27851:

> As @Tratcher pointed out there might be no way for this API to provide support in all hosting scenario as in case of IIS/Http.Sys it requires work in Http.Sys at the OS level.

Does anyone have creative workarounds so that we can get the client on to downloading resources while the page is still being generated (without giving up completely on Azure)?

Comment: Would you consider to use websockets or Azure SignalR?

Comment: Wrap Cloudflare around it.